# The button hover effects do not work after i use the fadeIn effect

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I want my button to first fade in then I want the hover effects to take place after the button has faded in.

The code can be found here. What can I do to activate the hover effects after the button has faded in.

here is the HTML code for the button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-white">discover our tours</a>
```

and here is the css code:

```
.btn:link,
.btn:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 30px;
    opacity: 0;

    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-out;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.btn:hover{
    transform: translateY(-3px);

}

.btn:active{
    transform: translateY(-1px);
}

.btn-white{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0);
    }
}
```

the entire code can also be viewed here https://codepen.io/mohits0631/pen/QWjJJEb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

animation-fill-mode: forwards sets your transform function based on the end of your animation which cant be overwritten. thats the reason only translate function isn't working there. During hover function you could manually set the animation-fill-mode to none and then set opacity to 1. Hope this works :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform),

> Only elements positioned by the box model can be transformed. As a rule of thumb, an element is positioned by the box model if it has `display: block`.

I modified your code to check:

```css
  .btn:hover{
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    color: green;
}
```

The `transform` did not work but the `color` worked, so I did

```css
.btn:hover{
  display:block;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  color: green;
}
```

and it worked

Comment: @MohitSingh please mark this answer as correct if it helped you for the sake of others. Thanks